# Visual C# bezier drawing problems

Tags: c#, bezier

I having an issue in a drawing application what I developing, in what bezier curves don't work as they should.

I have this code line:

```
g.DrawBezier(pen, points[i - 1], points[i], points[i], points[i + 1]);
```

It does his job nice, but for some reason it also paints an extra line what is very unhelpful...

[image: CLICK ME]

As you can see, for some reason, an awful line appears on top of the spline.

Can someone please help me?

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++) {
    pen.Color = colors[i];
    pen.Width = widths[i];
    if (visible[i] == true) {
        g.DrawBezier(pen, points[i - 1], points[i], points[i], points[i + 1]);
        if (spoints == true) {
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.LimeGreen, 5), points[i].X - 1, points[i].Y - 1, 2, 2);
            if (spositions == true) {
                g.DrawString(points[i].X.ToString() + ", " + points[i].Y.ToString(), new Font("Courier", 8), pen.Brush, points[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (sskeleton == true)
    {
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Magenta, 1), points[i].X, points[i].Y, points[i + 1].X, points[i + 1].Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code that duplicates the problem for us.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  You are drawing lines when sskeleton is true.  What is considered awful?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the DrawLine call at the bottom? Does that fix the issue?

Comment: This is another thing, and if I comment it the problem don't disapears

Comment: How does this: `g.DrawBezier(pen, points[i - 1], points[i], points[i], points[i + 1]);` even work when `i == 0` or `i == points.Count-1`? Are the first and last points "not visible"?

Comment: Yes it is invisible. Its a vectorial painting app

Comment: Based on bezier curves to smooth the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here's what's happening.

Say the points are

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>() {
    new Point(50, 50),
    new Point(150, 150),
    new Point(150, 250),
    new Point(300, 300),
    new Point(400, 300)};
```

The first bezier curve is drawn[image: First points]

The green dots are the actual points.  Notice that the curve doesn't actually go through the second point.

The next curve is drawn.[image: Next points]
This curve starts at the second point (not where the last curve went through).

Final plot:
[image: Final plot]

The middle two points in the DrawBezier function are control points, so the curve isn't guaranteed to go through those two points.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7h66bsy(v=vs.110).aspx

Perhaps what you're trying to accomplish could be done with DrawBeziers.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds101091(v=vs.110).aspx

Another option would be to start the next bezier curve at the end point of the last one (instead of at the control point of the last one).
[image: Starting at last end point]

If you want a curve that goes through all of the points, try DrawCurve(pen, points).
[image: DrawCurve]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was dancing around with this in my head but couldn't quite put it together without creating an actual example. Very nice visuals.

Comment: Nice! But there is some way with the native drawing functions to make a curve that goes through each of the points? Or I need to make the function by myself?

Comment: Yes, use DrawCurve()

Comment: I added an image of what I get with DrawCurve.  You can pass the entire array instead of doing it in the for loop.  In what way didn't it work for you?